# AuthenticationException throws with correct credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to secure a REST API with JWT and I have a problem during the sign in.

UserService.java

```
private final UserRepository repository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository repository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                   JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

public String signin(String email, String password) {
    try {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);
        authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        return jwtTokenProvider.createToken(email, Collections.singletonList(ROLE_CLIENT));
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new CustomException("Invalid email/password supplied", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}

public String signup(UsersEntity user) {
    if (!repository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        repository.save(user);
        return jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.getEmail(), Collections.singletonList(ROLE_CLIENT));
    } else {
        throw new CustomException("Email is already in use", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

It successfully signs up user, but when I'm trying to login it always throws an `AuthenticationException` on `authenticationManager.authenticate(token);`.

What m I doing wrong?

[Full stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/SiRnwDfC)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni updated

Comment: You should check the subtype of the `AuthenticationException`. Is it a `DisabledException`, a `LockedException` or a `BadCredentialsException`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni how to do it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the sigin method and check the type of the exception with your debugger. You can also step into the `AuthenticationManager.authenticate` method to understand the cause of the exception.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni bad credentials, https://pastebin.com/TRxept8Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stack traces you provided, the `BadCredentialsException` is thrown by the method `additionalAuthenticationChecks` from the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` class. Either the authentication token you provide is null or either the presented password extractred from this authentication token doesn't match with the password returned by the `getPassword` method of the `userDetails` object.

```
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
        logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
                "Bad credentials"));
    }

    String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
        logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
                "Bad credentials"));
    }
}
```